# Azure AD Authentication in Asp.net web forms web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have tried the azure ad authentication in asp.net web form application from a solution got from Microsoft docs.but is not working.The app is not redirect to Microsoft authorize login page.The error which i got is 401 unauthorized error.I don't know how it throwing.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/

this is the link which i referred.

This is my startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{ LoginPath=new PathString("/Login.aspx")});
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUrl,

            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,

            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        string currentUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = currentUrl;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

And this is my login page.

```
if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
             HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
             new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
             OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);


        }
```

I have one doubt regarding the redirecting our our aspx page.
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the below code sample i have posted in Github

https://github.com/azure-cxp-community/Azure_CXP_Comunity_Engineering/tree/master/src/DeveloperTools/WebApp.OpenIdConnect.Guide

Here is something you need to setup in your Azure AD:

1) Create app registration and add a reply URL as similar to your Web APP. in this example i my reply URL is http://localhost:2997/.

2) Add a permission to use Windows Azure Active Directory.

[image]

3) Grant permission for this app to use Active directory.
[image]

Your Application is good to start using Azure AD for authentication.

Download the code and change the client ID in the web.config solution and as per your application and you can proceed with the authentication.

Here is the code for Startup.Auth

```js
public class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID (a.k.a. Application ID) is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

        // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in
        string redirectUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUrl"];

        // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
        static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

        // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
        string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
                    
                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUrl,
                    
                    //Scope is the requested scope: OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenIdProfileis equivalent to the string 'openid profile': in the consent screen, this will result in 'Sign you in and read your profile'
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    
                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    
                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name or Id (example: contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

Here is the package.config list i am using in my sample.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.5" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mohit Verma                                                                                         I have one doubt, how we can redirect to an aspx page after sign out operation has to be done. currently my system behaves redirect to microsoft sign in page after sign out operation done. how i can resolve that?

Comment: There are 2 types of sign out - from your app and from your OpenIdConnect authentication provider (in your case Azure AD).  For the 1st you're simply calling System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie); then do a Response.Redirect to wherever you want.  For the 2nd, you can probably provide as a query string parameter.  To log someone out of Azure AD you can use this URL - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={1}` (0 = Tenant ID)